# Rails can't connect to locally installed firebird db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, firebird

I have a dockerized rails 4.2 app. I also installed a firebird 3 on my local Ubuntu machine. Now, when I start my docker container and want to start developing I always get this error:

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
>   No Firebird connections established.

This is my docker run command:

```
docker run --rm -itP --name dev-cont --network host -v $(pwd):/data -e NO_RAKE_TASK=1 image_name
```

This is my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: fb
  database: /var/lib/firebird/3.0/data/FELIX.FDB
  username: sysdba
  password: x
  host: localhost
  encoding: UTF-8
  charset: UTF-8
  #  create: true
```

I can connect to the database with my DB Admin tool (DBeaver), where the configuration looks exactly the same.

To see if the port is available in the container I installed nmap and checked if the port is open, which seems to be.

What am I missing here?

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the db? If you use "localhost" you will have to change that to the IP of your host.

Comment: You need to change your host from database.yml

Comment: I am using localhot, but because i am using the `--network host` run parameter it should be able to find localhost as well, shouldn't it?

Comment: I changed the host to my IP address now and it didn't change anything :-/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I already tried everything mention by Thomasleveil in this thread. Neither bridge mode nor host mode seems to work...

Comment: That is why I didn't vote as a duplicate, but maybe you hadn't checked everything in that question, and linking the question might help others in the future. I don't normally use Linux, but maybe you should look if commenting out or changing the `RemoteBindAddress` setting in the `firebird.conf`, or tweaking your xinetd config helps. Possibly if it is bound on 127.0.0.1 only, the docker image might not actually be able to connect (I'm not sure how docker handles this).

Comment: I ended up putting the firebird in a container as well and using docker-compose. This is working fine so far.